# I am looking for an Angular JS multiselect Tree view (with Checkbox ). Do you know any?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, treeview

I am looking for an Angular JS  multiselect Tree view (with Checkbox ). Do you know any? plz

Answer (score 0):

I recommended using the `Angular IVH Treeview` project. It's a treeview for AngularJS with filtering, checkbox support, custom templates, and more.

https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview

https://ivantage.github.io/angular-ivh-treeview/